# Splash screen appears everytime the project's starting window is invoked..

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have implemented a splashscreen for my project, it works well as desired.. but in my project i have an option of logout for user,this displays start page where a different login is provided(which is the starting screen..i.e, "chooselogin.xaml"). So when the user clicks on "choose a different login" while he already selected one in the application.. again the splashscreen appears, which is not required and looks odd.

the following code is what i think leading to problem... guys

```
public partial class Chooselogin : Window
 {
     public Chooselogin()
     {
         new SplashWindow().ShowDialog();
         InitializeComponent();
     }
```

......

This code is my "App.xaml"..

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 StartupUri="Chooselogin.xaml">
       <Application.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml"/>
       </Application.Resources>
```

The splash screen code is as follows..

```
public partial class SplashWindow : Window
    {
        Thread loadingThread;
        Storyboard Showboard;
        Storyboard Hideboard;
        private delegate void ShowDelegate(string txt);
        private delegate void HideDelegate();
        ShowDelegate showDelegate;
        HideDelegate hideDelegate;

        public SplashWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            showDelegate = new ShowDelegate(this.showText);
            hideDelegate = new HideDelegate(this.hideText);
            Showboard = this.Resources["showStoryBoard"] as Storyboard;
            Hideboard = this.Resources["HideStoryBoard"] as Storyboard;
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            loadingThread = new Thread(load);
            loadingThread.Start();
        }
        private void load()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(showDelegate, "Loading assets...please wait");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //do some loading work
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(hideDelegate);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(showDelegate, "Loading profiles..");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //do some loading work
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(hideDelegate);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(showDelegate, "Loading Data... almost done");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(hideDelegate);

            //close the window
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        (Action)delegate() { Close(); });
        }
        private void showText(string txt)
        {
            txtLoading.Text = txt;
            BeginStoryboard(Showboard);
        }
        private void hideText()
        {
            BeginStoryboard(Hideboard);
        }

}
```

The splash screen is supposed to be opened at start of application.. please help guys..

Comment: As `new SplashWindow().ShowDialog();` is in the constructor for `ChooseLogin` it will be invoked every time you create a ChooseLogin window. I'd suggest moving this line of code to a method you call once on Application startup.

Comment: Also, `.ShowDialog()` will block until the splash screen is closed. It will not continue to `InitializeComponent` before this has happened, so this is not a splash screen.

Comment: is this production code? i really hope not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something simple like this?:

```
public partial class Chooselogin : Window
{
    private static bool isFirstTime = true;

    public Chooselogin()
    {
        if (isFirstTime)
        {
            new SplashWindow().ShowDialog();
            isFirstTime = false;
        }
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...
}
```

Now it will only display the splash screen once.

Comment: I have checked it but what happened is.. every time when i choose a different login the object reference is used to show the choose login page like .. c.show() .. so what happens is again the "isFirstTime" variable is set to true.. and the problem persists.. I have come across this by debugging the module using two breakpoints..

Comment: What about if you make it `static`?

Comment: You are awesome... thanks for the comment.Thanks thanks thanks.... seriously you made my work easy...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [reading this post](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2012/12/wpf-splash-screens.html) by Kent Boogaart

**Example from the post**

*"WPF provides a SplashScreen class. It is simple by design and addresses the main goal of splash screens: immediate feedback. By virtue of forgoing the WPF stack and instead relying on Windows Imaging Component (WIC) to display images, it provides the quickest path to getting a splash on the screen short of writing your own native bootstrapper."*